# PHP/MySQL Display time since user's last login

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I don't know what kind of value I should store in the database.

I'm thinking I should do something like this, but I don't know how:

Store the years, days, hours, minutes since a give date like 1/1/2000
Then at another time I will compare that value against the current years, days, hours, and minutes since 1/1/2000.  Obviously, the difference between the two would be the time since the user's last login.

I appreciate any help anyone can provide on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, a datetime field is okay. You update it each time user logs in, and then get the difference between the current date and the one stored

Comment: You should store the unix timestamp. That is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 and is extremely well supported across just about every language.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a TIMESTAMP or a DATETIME? That's literally all you need.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql` will do this for you. It will store the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970. And calculate the difference.

Try this: `SELECT NOW();`. You will see now's date/time. Try `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());` and you'll see the number of seconds since Epoch (but you don't need that usually).

You should store this value everytime the user logs in, which means insert now() into a table or update a last_login field.

You have two options:

`INSERT INTO user_login_history (user_id, login_date) VALUES (1, NOW());`

and

`UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE user_id=1;`

Note that the `last_login` and `login_date` fields will have to be of either `DATETIME` type (to store date and time) or `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` (only date) or `TIME` (only time).

Also, you can do time calculations in mysql with `DATEDIFF`, like so:

`SELECT NOW(), DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE('2012-6-5'));`

In your table, `SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_login) AS "days_since_last_login" FROM users;`

Comment: If I use: SELECT NOW(), DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE('2012-6-5'));   How do I get the value into a variable so that I can use echo to print it?

Comment: You need to use `mysql_query`. Check [the example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to know how to use it. If it's not cleat enough, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the timestamp of the last login and then just do the arithmetic. Maybe you should look at the DateTime::diff method to let PHP do the hard maths ;-)