# Time since user's last login using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have checked this question ([PHP/MySQL Display time since user's last login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147746/php-mysql-display-time-since-users-last-login)) and it didn't helped me.

I have a user table in MySQL database. Here are the fields of user table.

```
uid
name
password
last_login (type = timestamp)
```

Whenever user login to website last_login field get updated with current date time `(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)`.

I am able to update last_login field and it is working properly.

Now, I want to show difference between now and last_login time. I tried SQL query to get the detail but it is not working. Here is the SQL query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_login) FROM user where uid=1");
```

I tried to check this query in phpMyAdmin but it returns 0.

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `0` means the user has logged in in the past day. Update user 1's last_login time to `2015-05-25 00:00:00`. You should get back `5`, I think.

Comment: how can i show it in year/month/day/hour/min/sec.

Comment: have you tried timediff instead of datediff?

Comment: ^ timediff should do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579946/only-show-hours-in-mysql-datediff

Comment: @pavlin chris85 Does timediff can give the output if hour is greater 24 then show 1 day. Similar for month year.

Comment: Actually check out this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111956/how-to-get-data-from-last-hour-last-day-and-last-month-with-one-query I think that is what you are after..

Comment: @chris85 It didn't helped. I think i will have to look for other php solution.

Comment: Just to check for the obvious here. If you run the difference query right *after* updating the last login field, the result of zero would be kinda obvious, if you check for datediff instead of timediff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of this answer, [How to get data from last hour, last day and last month with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111956/how-to-get-data-from-last-hour-last-day-and-last-month-with-one-query).

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) <= last_login THEN concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Minute, last_login, NOW()), ' Minute(s)') ELSE 0 END HOURLY, 
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) <= last_login THEN concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Hour, last_login, NOW()), ' Hour(s)') ELSE 0 
END DAILY, 
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) <= last_login THEN concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, last_login, NOW()), ' Day(s)') ELSE 0 
END MONTHLY,
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) <= last_login THEN concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, last_login, NOW()), ' Month(s)') ELSE 0 
END YEAR
FROM users WHERE userid = 2203 or userid = 1 or userid = 1746
```

<s>The first column to have a value `1` is when the user last logged in. The later columns will still validate because if they've logged in in the past hour they've logged in in the past day, etc.</s>

I'm not sure if this is easier to read now or not, it's no longer an empty/not check. Now it will display the difference in time from their last login in the column; the other greater columns (month, year, etc) will say 0s with the unit..

Comment: Updated with maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_login) FROM user where uid=1"
```

Returns 0, as the user has logged in today (days since last login)

You may use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) as well

```
"SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_login) FROM user where uid=1"
```

**For reference:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if user last logged on 2 days ago then it show it in hour. I don't want this. I want if its less than a day then show it in hour if its less than 30 days then show it as number of days. same for month and year.

Comment: In MySQL we can do that using  `CASE WHEN`, but its better to do that in PHP considering performance. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time)